# Symfony2 Routing optional parameter with trailing slash

Tags: symfony, parameters, routes, yaml, option-type

I am trying to write my first application with Symfony2. It's a fairly simple game just to get used to working with Symfony2, but the Routing is bugging me.

I use YAML for my routing and have the following routes:

```
upload:
    path: /{_locale}/upload/{currentGameType}/
    defaults:  { _controller: BaseAcmeBundle:Default:upload, currentGameType: gameName, _locale: nl }
    requirements:
        _locale: nl|en
```

The `currentGameType` is optional, and always is 'gameName', a default game if it is not set.

So when going to `en/upload` the route `upload:` is ignored and I get the message that the route is not found

When for example I go to the `en/upload/gameName` the route does work and the gametype is set to `gameName`. Why does this parameter not want to be optional?

So.. I am completely lost the pas few hours and wish for some help/pointers.

Thanks in advance.

**edit:** So, few minutes after posting I found out that without the trailing slashes in the routing it does work. However knowing this it is still an issue.

Answer (score 1):

just create a second path:

```
upload_bare:
    path: /{_locale}/upload/
    defaults:  { _controller: BaseAcmeBundle:Default:upload, _locale: nl }
    requirements:
        _locale: nl|en
```

just note that in your function you should have gameName = null by default and it should be your last argument.